# how to put sysdate as a default value for a date attribute in SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012-localdb

I'm using ASP.NET, I want to put the value sysdate (like in Oracle) as a default value for a date column in my SQL Server LocalDB.

I've tried to put `SYSDATE` and `SYSDATETIME` but it doesn't work.

Here is my table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profils] 
(
    [idProfil]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [login]           NVARCHAR (16)  NOT NULL,
    [password]        NVARCHAR (16)  NOT NULL,
    [email]           NVARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
    [dateCreation]    DATETIME NULL DEFAULT ???,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Profils] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idProfil] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no trouble whatsoever created this default constraint like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profils] 
(
    [idProfil]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [login]           NVARCHAR (16)  NOT NULL,
    [password]        NVARCHAR (16)  NOT NULL,
    [email]           NVARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
    [dateCreation]    DATETIME NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Profils] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idProfil] ASC)
);
```

Just use `DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()` and you should be fine.